# Passing values as reference to a constructor/function

Tags: c++

In my example I declared a class Player1. The constructor expects a read-only input and handles it as reference. Thats okay.

```cpp
class Player1 {
private:
  std::string m_Name;

public:
  Player1(const std::string &name) : m_Name(name) {}
  std::string GetName() { return m_Name; }
};
```

---

For instanciation either way (A) is possible:

```cpp
 std::string aName = "Chris"; //declare string-variable and assining value
  Player1 chris(aName); //passing the variable to the constructor which handles it as reference
```

---

Or the way (B) is possible:

```cpp
Player1 chris("Chris"); //direct text input
```

---

I dont get why the way B direct text input is okay for the compiler. From my point of view the constructor only accepts a reference, which is for me a pre-declared/assigned variable.

```cpp
Player1(const std::string &name)
```

The only explanation for me is that the constructor internally creates a variable which is handled as reference.

Does somebody have some clear words as an enlightment? I know its a rather small parts question. One could also say, well it works.

Comment: Implicit type constructor of `std::string`. There's a temporary `std::string` object created, whose lifetime is prolonged until the function returns.

Comment: I think the downvote here was a little mean.  After all, it's a fair question for those who don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tentative explanation is actually pretty close, but it differs in a couple of details from what actually happens. It's not the constructor that does any work here, the constructor still takes a `const std::string &` as a parameter. That part doesn't change, and nothing exceptional happens in the constructor, in this case.

It's the call site, where the constructor gets called (where the object gets constructed), is where the conversion happens. At the call site the string literal, which is a `const char [6]` gets used to construct a temporary `std::string` object. A `const char [n]` decays to a `const char *` when passed to a function or a method (such as a constructor). A `std::string` has a constructor that accepts a `const char *` as a parameter. So this boils down to a temporary `std::string` that gets constructed at the call site.

Then, the next domino falls, and a reference to the `std::string` gets passed to your object's constructor. That's another one of C++ rules: a temporary object can bind to a `const` reference.

Finally, after your `Player` gets constructed, the temporary `std::string` object gets destroyed.

All of the above steps are governed by a long, long list of various C++ rules that specify how implicit type conversions and constructors work, and are actually a somewhat of a simplification. But that's what's effectively happens, in this case.